# Websockets Javascript DES code issue

Tags: javascript, c, websocket, des

Following is the excerpt from noVNC code,

```
            if (this._sock.rQwait("auth challenge", 16)) { return false; }

        // TODO(directxman12): make genDES not require an Array
        var challenge = Array.prototype.slice.call(this._sock.rQshiftBytes(16));
            Util.Warn("Challenge " + challenge);
        var response = RFB.genDES(this._rfb_password, challenge);
            Util.Warn("Response " + response);
        this._sock.send(response);
            Util.Warn("Response " + response);
        this._updateState("SecurityResult");
        return true;
```

My understanding is that the client is asking sever to send challenge with code

```
this._sock.rQwait("auth challenge", 16)
```

Then server is sending a challenge which is being received by client in code

```
this._sock.rQshiftBytes(16)
```

Then the Password is DES encrypted using RFB.genDES and response ise sent over socket.

However on server side, which is a XVP proxy program, the code looks like

```
unsigned int major, minor, type, res, challenge[4], response[16];
```

...

```
        case XVP_STATE_CHALLENGE_AUTH:
        srandom((unsigned int)(time(NULL) ^ 0xdf214a30));
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            challenge[i] = (random() ^ 0x51a488ce);
        }
        if (!xvp_write_all(client_sock, challenge, sizeof(challenge)))
            return 1;
        xvp_proxy_state = XVP_STATE_RESPONSE_AUTH;
        xvp_proxy_writing = false;
        break;
    case XVP_STATE_RESPONSE_AUTH:
        if (!xvp_read_all(client_sock, response, 16))
            return 1;
        authok = (vm == xvp_multiplex_vm || wrongvm) ? false :
            xvp_password_vnc_ok(vm->password, client_ip,
                                (char *)challenge, (char *)response);
        xvp_proxy_state = XVP_STATE_CONFIRM_AUTH;
        xvp_proxy_writing = true;
        break;
```

The challenge array is only 4 byte and is being sent as it is using code

```
!xvp_write_all(client_sock, challenge, sizeof(challenge))
```

However my javascript log from following code shows array of 16 numbers.

```
Util.Warn("Challenge " + challenge);
```

e.g. Challenge 100,139,246,69,3,120,162,81,179,57,13,48,56,106,4,19

My question is whether java script is really reading 16 bytes from socket using this._sock.rQshiftBytes(16) and server is sending only 4 bytes on same socket ?